# Algebra and Geometry book

Tags: reference-request, contest-math

Hello can you find two free books:

1) Book for Algebra with Theorems, Techniques and Select Problems

2) Book for Geometry with Theorems, Techniques and Select Problems

I need urgent 
Thanks in advanced

Comment: What level are you looking for as these can be from grade school through very theoretical? Regards

Comment: For olympiad level.Thanks

Comment: [tag:reference-request] should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

Answer (score 7):

Schaum's outlines are inexpensive, and readily available (fairly low cost, and many libraries have them, too. See for example: [College Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635394).

Here's a geometry link: [Schaum's outline for Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071544127).

At that link, you'll also find links to Schaum's Outlines for Elementary Algebra, Intermediate Algebra, College Algebra, and Geometry. (Scroll down). There are also such outlines for Trigonometry and Precalculus.

See also the [Art of Problem Solving Website:](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/articles.php) very much a resource for students interested in challenging math, and math contests.

Comment: arber - you may still accept an answer, even if the question has been closed! Let me know if you've found these resources helpful! See also the Art of Problem solvings [discussion forum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewforum.php?f=217) for algebra and geometry problems, and collections of theorems, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Someone posted this link a while back at MSE. It's free (online), and covers the number-theoretic subset of algebra. So it isn't quite what you are looking for. http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/Santos%20-%20Number%20Theory%20for%20Mathematical%20Contests.pdf